# Xpath not working as expected while running the test

Tags: selenium

I am trying to automate the browser, while I try to locate the element via xpath in browser in static mode it is able to highlight the element where as when I run the script it comes back with an error that it is unable to find the element.

xpath I have written:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='soa_b_pbtv_l0_trnkni']/following-sibling::td[1]/child::select[@name='jobaction']")));
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<form name="f2" onsubmit="return verify();" action="/ATS/cgi-bin/barcap_jobaction.pl" method="post">
   <>
     <input name="jobname" type="hidden" value="soa_b_pbtv_l0_trnkni"/>
     <input name="jobinstance" type="hidden" value="D03"/>
     <input name="jobproceed" type="hidden" value="web"/>
  <td style="background-color: #ffffff;">
     <select name="jobaction">
```

Comment: Woudn't this be suffice `//input[@value='soa_b_pbtv_l0_trnkni']/following-sibling::td/select[@name='jobaction']`

Comment: That is not working .. <select> tag is child to td.

Comment: select is immediate child of td or descendant of td?

Comment: select is descendant of td

Comment: Then try like `//input[@value='soa_b_pbtv_l0_trnkni']/following-sibling::td/descendant::select[@name='jobaction']`

Comment: sorry my bad .. its child of td

Comment: For both the above should work

Comment: The thing is it works if I try to locate in browser without running script .. but does not work when I run the same via script.

Comment: Can you share the URL so we can take a look?

Answer (score 0):

if you're trying to select the `select`, `jobaction` then try this:

use css selector for the select `select[name='jobaction']`

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("form[name='f2']")));
List<WebElement> eleList = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("form[name='f2']")));
for(WebElement element: eleList)  {       
if(element.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[name='jobname']")).getText().equalsIgnoringCase("expectedValue")) {
        WebElement element = element.findElement(By.cssSelector("select[name='jobaction']"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks.. but there are more than 1 element with property <select name="jobaction" > ...Hence for that reason I have to use the value from the input tag as well to build the xpath.

Comment: updated my answer for if it's the child element or the form `f2`.. then it will work

Comment: Hence for that reason I had used the value from the input tag as well to build the xpath. 

"soa_b_pbtv_l0_trnkni"  is unique in the page

Comment: Sorry if I did not explained clearly.. but f2. is also repeating, only thing unique is value="soa_b_pbtv_l0_trnkni" in the input tag above

Comment: eleList is not returning any elements.

Comment: check that form visible or not, if it is not visible then use explicit wait for element to exist

Comment: do you need to wait for the form to fully display before you can interact with it?

Comment: No .. I do not need to wait for the element to fully display. Have added that in previous steps.

Comment: Updated my answer..@BreaksSoftware it's ideal to wait for page fully loaded

Answer (score 0):

The `INPUT` is hidden so it won't be found using typical Selenium means. Selenium was designed to only interact with elements that a user can see and interact with. You are able to locate it in the browser because you are using JS or JQuery and they are not designed to ignore hidden elements. One way to get around this is to use `JavascriptExecutor`... it basically allows you to run JS in Selenium and find hidden elements. Since it sounds like you already have successful locators, I would suggest you look up some tutorials on JSE and you should be set.

If you run into a new issue while using JSE, come back and post a new question and we can try to help you.